# Using nls function together with the apply function in R

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression

Thanks for the initial response.

Assume,I have a matrix as ;

```
X<-matrix(c(1:180),nrow=3)
```

If I want to apply the following nls function to each row using the apply function.

```
nls(
    k ~ a0 - a2*sin(((pi*0.01)/5)*t + phi1) + a4*sin(((2*pi*0.01)/5)*t + phi2) - a6*sin(((3*pi*0.01)/5)*t + phi3),
    data = X,
    start = list (a0=0.01,a2=0.01,a4=0.01, a6=0.01, phi1=0.21,phi2= -0.10, phi3=0.35)
   )
```

How do I program it? 
Again,since `k` the response variable is intuitively the rows of the above  matrix.

Comment: `nls` requires at least two variables to work with: a predictor and a response. If you're trying to run it on one row of your matrix, then you only have one variable. Perhaps you should rethink or clarify your approach.

Comment: Is `t` something like `1:180` ?  If `k` is the output, you need an input.    But anyway,  as I often do, I'd recommend going to cornell.edu and downloading `Eureqa` , which is designed exactly for finding good fits to combinations of input functions like this.